# Hosting a server-side websocket and a gui loop simultaneously

Tags: python, websocket, python-multithreading, pysimplegui

I'm trying to make a simple multiplayer lan Catan game, using a python host and website clients in js. The clients are fine, but I'm having issue with hosting the websocket (with the `websockets` library) and running a gui loop (using PySimpleGUI) in parallel, at the same time, with the `threading` library. Here's a (hopefully) minimal example:

```py
import asyncio
import json
import websockets
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import threading

async def gameLogicHandler(event, ws):
    <handle client input>

async def handler(websocket):
    while True:
        try:
            message = await websocket.recv()
        except websockets.ConnectionClosedOK:
            break
        await gameLogicHandler(json.loads(message), websocket)

layout = [[sg.Text('Catan Server', size=(20, 1), justification='center', font='Helvetica 20')],
          [sg.Text('Players:')],
          [sg.Multiline(size=(20, 10), key='players')]]

window = sg.Window('Catan Server', layout)

def updateGui():
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        window["players"].update('\n'.join([player.name for player in players])) # player object I'm using that isn't included here
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
            exit()

async def main_socket():
    async with websockets.serve(handler, "", 8001):
        await asyncio.Future()

def main():
    t = threading.Thread(target=updateGui)
    t.start()
    asyncio.run(main_socket())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm sure there's numerous mistakes, and I'm rather new to all of these libraries, as well as asking questions on Stack Overflow, so please don't be too harsh.

However, the updateGui function just runs once, instead of constantly. (If I put a print statement in it, it's only in the console once). If you have any insights, it's very much appreciated. Thank you :)

Edit: I have discovered that the function is pausing on the line `event, values = window.read()` for some reason - if I put another print after that line, it would not run until the window was closed.

Comment: Can't run the GUI in a thread.

Comment: @MikefromPSG what makes you say that? I fixed this a couple days ago and forgot to resolve the page and it works fine in a thread.

Comment: https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#multiple-threads

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have fixed this, after many headaches, so maybe this can help someone later.

I changed my updateGui function to this:

```py
def updateGui():
    while True:
        event = window.read(100, None)
        if event != None:
            if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
                exit()
        window["players"].update('\n'.join([player.name for player in players]))
```

This is because the window.read method halts until an event happens - which is not what I want. So I added a timeout of 100ms to the function, which lets the loop progress normally.

Answer (score 1):

Something wrong

- Should run GUI in main thread
- `event = window.read(100, None)`, it should be `event, values = window.read(100, None)`, `None` here will be the `timeout_key` and same as `sg.WIN_CLOSED`.

```py
def updateGui():

    while True:

        event = window.read(timeout=100)

        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
                break
        elif event == sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT:
            window["players"].update('\n'.join([player.name for player in players]))

    window.close()
```

Comment: Yes, I realised this in my answer below - and I needn't include "values" as I'm not even checking that yet. But thank you :)